# Splash screen showing as background on every page

Tags: android, xamarin

My splash screen is shown at the beginning but then it stays running as if it were a background for the pages. I have to use BackgroundColor so that the background is not visible but any transition shows the background very briefly.

This is my MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace apptest.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "apptest", Icon = "@drawable/appmain", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

           
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my SplashActivity.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Util;

namespace apptest.Droid
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof (SplashActivity).Name;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
        }

        // Launches the startup task
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
            startupWork.Start();
        }

        // Prevent the back button from canceling the startup process
        public override void OnBackPressed() { }

        // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
        async void SimulateStartup ()
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
            await Task.Delay(8000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof (MainActivity)));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the splash screen disappear?

Please and Thank you! :)

Comment: Change the theme in the MainActivity to be a blank theme, not the 'Splash' theme.

Answer (score 1):

Like David said, do not set the Splash theme for the MainActivity. You could use the default Theme created by the project.

```
 [Activity(Label = "SplashScreen", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

You could download the source file from the Github for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/SplashScreen